# How To Connect to an already created Chalice Project and AWS Lambda Environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, chalice

Beginner Chalice question here!

I would like to connect to and modify a chalice project created by a team member that includes multiple lambda functions. I have already setup my AWS environment to connect to the same account, have git cloned the code, and can see the Lambda functions that were already created. **My question is:** How do I setup my Chalice environment such that when I do a `chalice deploy` the existing lambda functions are updated and I'm not creating a bunch of new ones (and IAM roles etc) in our AWS Account?

In the [Chalice CLI source code](https://github.com/aws/chalice/blob/67601af4002346b40027a409608e3a4c998c9376/chalice/cli/__init__.py) the only project initiation command listed is `chalice new-project`; that is, there is no  `chalice connect-to-existing-project --name XXX`. If I do the following will my lambda functions be updated instead of creating new ones: (1) ensure i'm connected to the same AWS account (2) keep the project folders the same names and (3) keep my chalice routes in the code the same name? Wanted to check before I start spamming resources; any details appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `chalice new-project` just creates some files for you. Since you already have those files, you should be able to simply run `chalice deploy`.

Comment: Your team-mate, who deployed the original, probably has some valuable advice here.